# Packing bits in C using bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Say I have an unsigned char array of ASCII characters with the binary values:

```
00001100  00011100  00110100  00111000 00110100  00100100  00010010  00011100  00100100 00010000  00011011  00001110  00001010 00011101  00100101
```

I don't need the two most significant bits of each byte (i.e. i only need the 6 least significant bits of each byte):

```
--001100  --011100 --110100  --111000 --110100  --100100  --010010  --011100  --100100 --010000  --011011  --001110 --001010  --011101 --100101
```

I'm trying to pack these bits into a single unsigned character array by placing the least significant bits of the next element in the array in the previous element's remaining bits. The final result should look like:

```
00001100  01000111  11100011  00110100  00101001  01110001  00100100  10110100  00111001  01001010  01010111  00000010
```

Hopefully you can see the pattern.

I'm currently trying to implement this using a nested for loop, but can't get the proper results:

```
void pack(unsigned char *message)
{
    unsigned char mask[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};
    unsigned char packed_bits[MAX_PACK_SIZE];

    int i, j, k, l, m;
    int count = 0;

    // initialize packed bits
    for (k = 0; k < MAX_PACK_SIZE; k++)
        packed_bits[k] = 0;

    // loop through message array
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_UNPACK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        // loop through message[i]'s bits
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            j = count;

            if (count == 6 && j == 6)
            {
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[0]) & mask[j + 0];
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[1]) & mask[j + 1];
                count = 2;
                break;
            }
            else if (count == 6 && j == 4)
            {
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[0]) & mask[j + 0];
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[1]) & mask[j + 1];
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[2]) & mask[j + 2];
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[3]) & mask[j + 3];
                count = 4;
                break;
            }
            else if (count == 6 && j == 2)
            {
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[0]) & mask[j + 0];
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[1]) & mask[j + 1];
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[2]) & mask[j + 2];
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[3]) & mask[j + 3];
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[4]) & mask[j + 4];
                packed_bits[i] += (message[i + 1] & mask[5]) & mask[j + 5];
                count = 0;
                ++i;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                packed_bits[i] += message[i] & mask[j];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (m = 0; m < MAX_PACK_SIZE; m++)
    {
        printf("packed_bits[%d]=%d\n", m, packed_bits[m]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly looks like a job for the debugger.

Comment: What do you want to do if `(original_bytes * 6) % 8 != 0` ?

Comment: Particularly if `(original_bytes * 6) % 8 == 2`. That means the final result will be ambiguous from the `((original_bytes + 1) * 6) % 8` case if the last byte were to be `0`.

Comment: I assume this is for serialization? For network transmission or some kind of data storage compression?

Comment: It seems like you should be able to narrow things down a little more. Maybe use a simpler example, maybe *include the actual and expected results*, and maybe step through the code with a debugger so we know which statements to focus on?

Comment: You have `for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)` followed by `j = count;` and later `else if (count == 6 && j == 4)`. That cannot work. The `for` loop is broken by modifying `j` separately, and that `if` test  can never be true after `j` is set to `count`. Rethink your code.

Comment: General solution to problems like is, write small functions. Such as, just as an example, `char get_6_bits(const char *src, size_t bit_offset);` and `void put_6_bits(char *dst, size_t bit_offset, char data);`. And then you would call these in a loop, after testing individually, that they work.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm brand new to this. I'll try to make smaller functions. What confuses me the most is how I need to keep track of how many bits I added (to the previous byte) from the next byte. That means when actually iterating to the next byte, some of the bits have already been packed in the previous element and I need to know which bit to start on.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

For OP's problem, all the bit fiddling becomes a little bit easier to master using some “manual” loop unrolling.

Packing 6 bits of each byte tightly means that

- 8 bytes will be packed to 6 bytes, and
- 4 bytes will be packed to 3 bytes

ending in both cases with a full byte output.

Hence, I wrote a loop which always packs 4 bytes at once.

The end of input might not be aligned to 4. So, there is a special handling necessary for the at most 3 bytes at the end.

My MCVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t pack(const unsigned char *message, size_t len, unsigned char *packed_bits)
{
  size_t i = 3, j = 0;
  // handle bulk
  for (; i < len; i += 4, j += 3) {
    packed_bits[j + 0] = ((message[i - 3] & 0x3f) >> 0) | ((message[i - 2] & 0x03) << 6);
    packed_bits[j + 1] = ((message[i - 2] & 0x3c) >> 2) | ((message[i - 1] & 0x0f) << 4);
    packed_bits[j + 2] = ((message[i - 1] & 0x30) >> 4) | ((message[i - 0] & 0x3f) << 2);
  }
  // handle end (which might be not a full package of 4 bytes)
  if (i - 3 < len) {
    packed_bits[j++] = message[i - 3] & 0x3f;
  }
  if (i - 2 < len) {
    packed_bits[j - 1] |= (message[i - 2] & 0x03) << 6;
    packed_bits[j++] = (message[i - 2] & 0x3c) >> 2;
  }
  if (i - 1 < len) {
    packed_bits[j - 1] |= (message[i - 1] & 0x0f) << 4;
    packed_bits[j++] = (message[i - 1] & 0x30) >> 4;
  }
  // i < len is not possible because it would've been handled in for loop.
  return j;
}

void printBits(const unsigned char *buf, size_t len);

int main(void)
{
  // sample data
  unsigned char message[] = {
#if 0 // gcc extension
    0b00001100, 0b00011100, 0b00110100, 0b00111000,  0b00110100, 0b00100100, 0b00010010, 0b00011100,
    0b00100100, 0b00010000, 0b00011011, 0b00001110,  0b00001010, 0b00011101, 0b00100101
#else // the same in hex
    0x0c, 0x1c, 0x34, 0x38, 0x34, 0x24, 0x12, 0x1c, 0x24, 0x10, 0x1b, 0x0e, 0x0a, 0x1d, 0x25,
#endif // 0
  };
  const size_t len = sizeof message / sizeof *message;
  // output buffer
  unsigned char packed_bits[len]; // len is a bit over-pessimistic but definitely sufficient ;-)
  // pack the sample
  const size_t len_packed = pack(message, len, packed_bits);
  // report
  printf("message[%zu]:\n", len);
  printBits(message, len);
  printf("packed to packed_bits[%zu]:\n", len_packed);
  printBits(packed_bits, len_packed);
  return 0;
}

void printBits(const unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    unsigned byte = buf[i];
    printf(" %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c",
      byte & 0x80 ? '1' : '0',
      byte & 0x40 ? '1' : '0',
      byte & 0x20 ? '1' : '0',
      byte & 0x10 ? '1' : '0',
      byte & 0x08 ? '1' : '0',
      byte & 0x04 ? '1' : '0',
      byte & 0x02 ? '1' : '0',
      byte & 0x01 ? '1' : '0');
  }
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Output:

```
message[15]:
 00001100 00011100 00110100 00111000 00110100 00100100 00010010 00011100 00100100 00010000 00011011 00001110 00001010 00011101 00100101
packed to packed_bits[12]:
 00001100 01000111 11100011 00110100 00101001 01110001 00100100 10110100 00111001 01001010 01010111 00000010
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ac3b040fb728444)

---

I compared my output to expected output of OP, and they match.

The input of OP and mine:

```
00001100 00011100 00110100 00111000 00110100 00100100 00010010 00011100 00100100 00010000 00011011 00001110 00001010 00011101 00100101
00001100 00011100 00110100 00111000 00110100 00100100 00010010 00011100 00100100 00010000 00011011 00001110 00001010 00011101 00100101
```

Exactly equal.

The expected output of OP and mine:

```
00001100 01000111 11100011 00110100 00101001 01110001 00100100 10110100 00111001 01001010 01010111 00000010
00001100 01000111 11100011 00110100 00101001 01110001 00100100 10110100 00111001 01001010 01010111 00000010
```

Exactly equal.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I was looking for the lowest bit of the next byte to fill the next highest bit of the previous byte (i.e. --001100 --011100 --->> [b][a]001100 --0111[b][a].) I'm not exactly sure what went wrong in your code, but I appreciate your help. I'll try to look through it now.

Comment: @Frenchi33 You are correct. There were some stupid bugs. I should've checked on "paper" to find it myself. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to do this. Here is one that should be easy to understand. (It uses a GCC extension, binary literals, to provide the sample data.)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//  Calculate the number of elements in an array.
#define NumberOf(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof *(a))


//  Make a mask in which the n low bits are set.
#define Mask(n) ((1u << n) - 1)


//  Divide x by y, rounding up to the next integer.
#define DivideUp(x, y)  (((x) + (y) - 1) / (y))


/*  Pack the lower six bits of each of the NI elements in In to the Out,
    putting eight bits in each element of Out.  SO is the number of elements
    available in Out.  The number of output elements used is returned.
*/
static size_t pack(unsigned char *Out, size_t SO,
    const unsigned char *In, size_t NI)
{
    //  Test whether the output buffer is large enough.
    if (SO < DivideUp(NI*6, 8))
    {
        printf("Error, output buffer is %zu bytes but need %zu.\n",
            SO, DivideUp(NI*6, 8));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //  Use NO to count output bytes.
    size_t NO = 0;

    //  Initialize a buffer.
    uint32_t Buffer = 0;

    //  Process each input element.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NI; ++i)
    {
        //  Put the incoming six bits at their place in the buffer.
        Buffer |= (In[i] & Mask(6)) << i%4 * 6;

        //  After each four bytes, write the buffer to the output and reset it.
        if (i % 4 == 3)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
                Out[NO++] = Buffer >> j*8;
            Buffer = 0;
        }
    }

    //  Process any residual bytes remaining in the buffer.
    size_t Residue = NI % 4;
    if (Residue)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < DivideUp(Residue*6, 8); ++j)
            Out[NO++] = Buffer >> j*8;

    return NO;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned char In[] =
    {
        0b00001100,
        0b00011100,
        0b00110100,
        0b00111000,
        0b00110100,
        0b00100100,
        0b00010010,
        0b00011100,
        0b00100100,
        0b00010000,
        0b00011011,
        0b00001110,
        0b00001010,
        0b00011101,
        0b00100101,
    };

    unsigned char Observed[] =
    {
        0b00001100,
        0b01000111,
        0b11100011,
        0b00110100,
        0b00101001,
        0b01110001,
        0b00100100,
        0b10110100,
        0b00111001,
        0b01001010,
        0b01010111,
        0b00000010,
    };

    unsigned char Expected[NumberOf(Observed)];
    size_t N = pack(Expected, NumberOf(Expected), In, NumberOf(In));

    if (N != NumberOf(Observed))
    {
        printf("Error, expected %zu bytes but got %zu bytes.\n",
            NumberOf(Observed), N);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        if (Expected[n] != Observed[n])
        {
            printf(
"Error, expected byte %zu to be %#02hhx but observed %#02hhx.\n",
                n, Expected[n], Observed[n]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    printf("No error found.\n");
}
```